# Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 3 Setup keeps failing on my WIndows 8 PC

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation, visual-studio-community

I have looked at some other questions on this, but nothing seemed to help. So i decided to ask myself, hope that is okay :)

Also im not a tech genius, so sorry if i might not be able to understand some of the explenations. I have been coding for 9 months, and i learned to code on Visual Studio. I now want to install it on my own PC, but i can't make it work after around 10+ installs.

I have a Windows 8 laptop

I have tried both the web installer and the ISO install, on both my C: drive and D: drive. My D: drive is currently empty at around 250gb, which makes it easier to see what got installed and what to remove etc.

I have tried clearing the %Temp% folder, deleting all the Visual Studio files i could find.

My VCRedist_x64 and X86 are not the same size as far as i could see.

I tried repairing the program, re-install, restart and repair/install etc

I also tried installing only the minimum required, so i unchecked everything else when i installed.

Here is my error message
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVGl0.png)

I appreciate any help you guys and girls can provide, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the error message and the solution that you tried, you can have a look at this similar issue: [Error 1722. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/smondal/2016/05/04/error-1722-there-is-a-problem-with-this-windows-installer-package/), check the team explorer log and VSIXInstaller log or directly share the vslogs.zip folder to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here.

If you can found the same “ViewDesigner” MSI in the MSIINV log, the resolution was to remove the “Studio 5000 View Designer” program from Programs and Features (Control Panel) or running this command from an admin prompt: msiexec /X {xxxxxxxxx}

If this same issue persists, you can try to use the [VisualStudioUninstaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller) to completely remove the existing VS 2015, then reinstall it with the default installation. Before the next installation, make sure windows update is up-to-date, temporary disable any antivirus, then run the installer as administrator.

Comment: I downloaded the VisualStudioUninstaller you mentioned, it says i need to run the executable. However i can't find any .exe file, only a .sln file.

Comment: Sorry, accidently pressed enter, and i can't edit my comment. How do i go about uninstalling/launching this tool?

Comment: @Saibo7, it looks like you downloaded the source code of this tool, you can scroll down and there is the tool download link: https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases and click it to redirect to the special download page, and download the release 5 TotalUninstaller.zip and use it to uninstall.

Comment: I used the Uninstaller, it told me i had a folder with the vs_Community.exe inside the ProgramCache folder. I told it to uninstall, but nothing happened. I ended up deleting it manually. I then checked if i had any Visual Studio files left, and i couldn't find any. So i tried a fresh install from the ISO again, however i got the exact same error as before. The only change i saw was the minimum install needing 5GB this time, instead of 2GB and i could specify the install location while it was greyed out previusly.

Comment: After the re-install, the uninstaller seemed to work as intended and uninstalled all the files related to Visual Studio. I will try to install the program again, to see if it changed anything.

Comment: @Saibo7, it looks like your issue is solved? If you think my reply is helpful, you can mark it as answer, so other community members who meet the same or similar issue can easier search it. If you still meet the installation issue, you can update it in here and share the installation logs like I said before.

Comment: Sadly i still have the original problem, the only log file i have is the one i got after the installation called "dd_vs_community_20161228152616.log". Do you want me to share that?

Comment: @Saibo7, to collect the whole installation logs, you can use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder then upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here.